# Why are all rainbows are not the same?

Tags: atmosphere, geophysics, light, rain

How does these rainbows water drops differ? I know it has to do with the size of water drops refracting light.

Is there a formula that determines the type of rainbow?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Icebow

[image]

Unlike this [questions](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9180/what-actually-happens-to-reduce-the-perceived-color-in-a-white-rainbow-or-fog?noredirect=1&lq=1) answer it does not illustrate how the reduction of water drops make less color. Also this ice bow does not follow this rule of thumb in that question.

Illustrations would be great!

Comment: Here you have asked four different questions; please edit your question to specify your problem. I cannot downvote, so I'll just have to leave it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarification. I'll try to answer all four :)

Comment: I recommend reading some articles on Wikipedia, then asking one question at a time. Your questions should be fairly specific.

Comment: This is a duplicate of an number of questions that have been asked on this site: Fog Bows: [What actually happens to reduce the perceived color in a 'white rainbow“ or ”fog-bow"? ](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9180/what-actually-happens-to-reduce-the-perceived-color-in-a-white-rainbow-or-fog/9182#9182), [what causes rainbow, the colours and the shape ](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/7480/what-causes-rainbow-the-colours-and-the-shape). In the stack exchange search area just enter rainbows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What actually happens to reduce the perceived color in a 'white rainbow" or "fog-bow"?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9180/what-actually-happens-to-reduce-the-perceived-color-in-a-white-rainbow-or-fog)

Comment: Only the fog bow helped so far but only a partial answer for this question thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is between the top two? (except that one has been massively enhanced in photoshop)